# Exit search box by clicking anywhere else on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search-box

I built a sliding down search box.  When you press the search icon a search box drops down, and if you press the search icon the search box will disappear again.  I want another way for people to exit the search box besides just clicking on the search icon again.  I also want to be able to exit the search box by clicking anywhere else on the screen besides the search box.  How would I do this?

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pkhj0frp/

```js
jQuery('.search-icon').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('.search-form').toggleClass('search-visible');
});
```

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Search
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.search-icon {
  float: right;
  line-height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px 34px;
}

.search-form {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
  background: #fff;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: calc((100vw - 1200px) / 2);
  padding-right: calc((100vw - 1200px) / 2);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(20% + 1px);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.search-form.search-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 110px;
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent {
  border-bottom: none;
  height: 100px !important;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  transform: none;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .input-group {
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .button-search {
  color: #33f;
  outline: none;
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .button-search:hover {
  color: #b4c5cd;
}

.search-form .input-group {
  margin-left: 18px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.search-form .form-control {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none !important;
  width: calc(100% - 36px) !important;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'freightlight';
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-color: inherit !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.search-form .form-control:focus {
  background: #fff !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-color: inherit !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}

.search-form .button-search {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 6px 0 0 0;
  width: 36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-icon"><img src="https://www.nature.org/cs/groups/webasset/documents/webasset/search-icon.png"></div>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form-inline" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" value="" name="s" class="input-sm search-field form-control" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit" class="button-search icon-search"></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create exit the search box by clicking anywhere else on the screen and keypress shortcut.

```
jQuery('.search-icon').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  jQuery('.search-form').toggleClass('search-visible');
});

$(window).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode == 117) {
    $('.search-form').toggleClass('search-visible');
  }
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $('.search-form').removeClass('search-visible');
})
```

Comment: Hi Murad.  I know you already answered this question, but I realized even when you press inside of the search box the search box will close.  So there is no way to enter anything in the search box since it will close if you click inside of it.  Is there anyway you can help fix this?  Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hdryt8yx/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2q5vLwh0/ I think this help you 2 bug fixed 1 click only document html close 2 keydown prevent default only keycode 117